# Activation issue with Cartalyst Sentinel native with Slim Framework

Tags: php, slim, cartalyst-sentinel

I want to use Cartalyst-Sentinel natively with Slim framework (not Laravel). Sentinel object work correctly (I use `Sentinel::register` method without problem) but when I use Activation object (example with `Activation::create()`method), receive the follow error:

> Call to a member function create() on a non-object in ...\vendor\illuminate\support\Facades\Facade.php on line 210

This is my code:

```
    $data = Sentinel::register($credentials);
    $user = Sentinel::findById($data['id']);
    $activation = Activation::create($user);
```

This is a part of my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "slim/slim": "^2.6",
    "entomb/slim-json-api": "dev-master",
    "symfony/http-foundation": "^2.7",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^5.4",
    "respect/validation": "^0.9.3",
    "cartalyst/sentinel": "^2.0",
    "illuminate/database": "^5.1",
    "illuminate/events": "^5.1"
},
```

thanks

Comment: I confirm that $user is a valid object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Activation class provided with Sentinel is only supported by Laravel directly not the Native Laravel/Database library for some strange reason.

Consider using Sentry instead if possible. It's also made by Cartalyst and it is essentially the same library with less features but seems to be overall less buggy and manages dependencies better than Sentinel. It also has more reliable documentation overall.

EDIT: You can get the Activation Repository for Native by replacing...

`Activation::` with `Sentinel::getActivationRepository()`

Answer (score 1):

just use , it's working with me like that:

```
$data = Sentinel::register($credentials);
$user = Sentinel::findById($data['id']);
$activation = Sentinel::activate($user);
```

return 1 if good , empty if not.

Answer (score 0):

So if we look at the error message you got:

```
Call to a member function create() on a non-object in ...\vendor\illuminate\support\Facades\Facade.php on line 210
```

That "non-object" is your `$user` variable.  It looks to me as though `Sentinel::findById($data['id']);` is supposed to be returning an object representing a user by looking up the provided `id`.  For whatever reason, it's not finding that user, so it is probably returning `null` or `false` instead.  If that is acceptable behavior for your application, then you could do something like:

```
$data = Sentinel::register($credentials);
$user = Sentinel::findById($data['id']);
if ($user){
    // The user was successfully found
    $activation = Activation::create($user);
} else {
    // Generate an error/exception/message here indicating that the user could not be found, or take them to the 404 page, etc.
    ...
}
```

I don't know enough about your application to say what it should do in the `else` case.

Comment: Thanks but the $user object is valid. I have checked it. I suppose that Activation instance is not initialized by Sentinel